# Excel: Average the largest (or smallest) N values in a range, excluding zeros

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, average

I'm trying to average the largest (or smallest) N values in a range that are non zeros. Say my data is on column A, I am using this formula:

`=AVERAGE(SMALL(A:A,{1,2,3}))`

which averages the three smallest values in A. A similar formula can be used with `LARGE` in place of `SMALL`, for the largest values. How can adapt the formula to find the smallest (largest) N values that are non zero, and average only those? I probably have to play with array formulas, `IFs`, and `"<>0"`, but I'm not very familiar with the excel syntax.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the numbers are zero or greater, check for the number of values that are zero, and start your `SMALL` above them:

```
=AVERAGE(SMALL(myRange,{1,2,3}+COUNTIF(myRange,0)))
```

IF some values might be less than zero, then

```
=AVERAGE(SMALL(IF(A:A<>0,A:A),{1,2,3}))
```

entered as an array formula by holding down `CTRL + SHIFT` while hitting `ENTER`.

Comment: Thanks! I just tested the formulas you proposed and they both work well, except in the (really borderline) case when there are less than 3 non-zeros. In that case the formula returns an error.

I fixed this concatenating `IFERROR`s, and progressively checking for the best 2, or the single best non-zero, with a final dummy value if everything fails. It looks a bit inelegant, but works. Are there alternatives?

`=IFERROR(AVERAGE(SMALL(A:A,{1,2,3}+COUNTIF(A:A,0))), IFERROR(AVERAGE(SMALL(A:A,{1,2}+COUNTIF(A:A,0))), IFERROR(AVERAGE(SMALL(A:A,{1}+COUNTIF(A:A,0))), MAX(A:A))))`

Comment: If that is something you need to test for, you could try this formula entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`:  `=IFERROR(AVERAGE(SMALL(IF(A:A<>0,A:A),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MIN(3,COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>0",A:A,"<>")))))),"no non-zero entries")`  I don't know which would be more efficient, but this one is volatile, which means it might be less efficient, but more easy to generalize if your desired number to average will vary.